# Как заменить многочисленные if на словарь, где ключ это имя метода, а значение это сам метод {'push_back': object.push_back,}?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    count_command = int(input())
    queue_length = int(input())
    queue = Deck(queue_length)
    for i in range(count_command):
        command = input()
        operation, *value = command.split()
        if value:
            if operation == 'push_back':
                a = queue.push_back(int(*value))
                if a is not None:
                    print(a)
            if operation == 'push_front':
                a = queue.push_front(int(*value))
                if a is not None:
                    print(a)
        else:
            if operation == 'pop_front':
                print(queue.pop_front())
            if operation == 'pop_back':
                print(queue.pop_back())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
def main():
    count_command = int(input())
    queue_length = int(input())
    queue = Deck(queue_length)
    operation_dict = {
        'push_back': queue.push_back,
        'push_front': queue.push_front,
        'pop_front': lambda: print(queue.pop_front()),
        'pop_back': lambda: print(queue.pop_back()),
    }
        
    for i in range(count_command):
        command = input()
        operation, *value = command.split()
        if value:            
            a = operation_dict[operation](int(*value))
            if a is not None:
                print(a)
        else:
            operation_dict[operation]()
```

Comment: Код работает, но немного не так, не пойму почему. Выводит числа в каком-то произвольном порядке, а нужно строго последовательно.

Comment: @АндрейК покажите ввод. и ожидаемый вывод

Comment: спасибо вам! Код отличный, только два раза push_back. И я не заметил )

Comment: @АндрейК и вправду. опечатался. сейчас поправлю